# How to show that elements in these groups pairwise commute?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, group-presentation

Let $F_2$ be the free group on $x,y$ and $N$ the normal subgroup generated by $x^2,y^4,xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$. Consider the group $F_2/N$ and two elements $xN$ and $yN$ in it. How do I show that elements in the subgroups generated by $xN$ and $yN$ pairwise commute?

Answer (score 1):

Recall, that you've got a well defined group-homomorphism $x\mapsto xN$ (namely, the quotient map), which implies $(xN)(yN)=(xy)N$. For simiplicity, I'll avoid using the notation $xN$ for the elements of the quotient, and I'll just write $x$.

Note that in $F_2/N$, you have $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=1$, so $xy=yx$ in $F_2/N$ for all $x,y\in F_2$. Since $x^2=1$ and $y^4=1$ in $F_2/N$ you only have to check that $x$ commutes with $y^2$ and $y^3$, which is immediate since $xy^2=xyy=yxy=y^2x$, and the same works for $y^3$.

Comment: I thought about it but I don't know how it implies the result. This shows that $xyN=yx$ and $yxN=xy$.

Comment: Since you're working in the quotient, it actually implies that the equivalence classes (or cosets)  $xyN$ and $yxN$ are equal.

Comment: Why does this follow? And even if $xyN=yxN$, this doesn't directly imply that all elements of the form $xn$ commute with elements of the form $yn'$.

Comment: Because you've got the well-defined group-homomorphism from $F_2$ to $F_2/N$ sending $x\mapsto xN$. And hence, $(xN)(yN)=xyN$.


Anyway, I think I misunderstood what you were supposed to prove. I'll keep your notation. Since $xN$ commutes with $yN$, clearly $xN$ commutes with $y^2N$ and $y^3N$ (there are no more elementes in the subgroup generated by $yN$). Since the subgroup generated by $xN$ has only one element, you're done.

Comment: Note: since your considering $xN$ and $yN$ as elements of the quotient, you don't need the $n$ in $xn$ nor the $n'$ in $yn'$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes things more clear. But what I can see now is that this group homomorphism business implies that $(xN)(yN)=(xy)N$ and $(yN)(xN)=(yx)N$. But why are the right hand sides equal? Once this is proved, the rest seems to be clear. For your remark in the last comment: why is that so? By definition elements of the set $xN$ are of the form $xn$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73854/discussion-between-javi-and-user527831).